# Confusing Output in Java Program

Tags: java, console, output, tostring, println

I'm new to Java programming and I'm following a guide on Udemy. I'm working with data manipulation through classes, this one being a simple name formatter. Predefined strings (parts of a name) are inserted into the class to format them.

This program uses two classes: Name.java and NameTest.java (the driver file)

***Name.java***:

```
package javaProject;

    public class Name { 
        private String first;
        private String middle;
        private String last;

        public Name(String f, String m, String l){
            first = f;
            middle = m;
            last = l;
        }

        public Name(String f, String l){
            first = f;
            middle = "";
            last = l;
        }

        public Name(String f){
            first = f;
            middle = "";
            last = "";
        }

        public Name(){
            first = "";
            middle = "";
            last = "";
        }
        ///
        public String displayName(){    
            return first + " " + middle + " " + last; 
        }


    public static void main(String[] args){

    }

}
```

***NameTest.java***:

```
package javaProject;

public class NameTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Name myName = new Name("Damon", "myMiddleName", "myLastName");
        System.out.println("My Name: " + myName.toString());
    }

}
```

***Output***:

```
My Name: javaProject.Name@35afe17b
```

Any idea why I'm getting this after specifying that the output should be a string? I'm not exactly sure how to fix this because, again, I'm really new to Java.

Comment: You need to define your own toString(), usually your IDE can do this for you as it's rather tedious.  Why Java doesn't do this for you is likely to be historical.  It gives you the class name and the identity hashCode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to support println in a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27647567/how-to-support-println-in-a-class)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4

Answer (score 4):

Rename your method, displayName does not **override** [Object.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) which is what you want;

```
// public String displayName(){ // <--- toString()
public String toString() {    
  return first + " " + middle + " " + last; 
}
```

There is a second option though (but note the advantage of the `toString()`),  and that is

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Name myName = new Name("Damon", "myMiddleName", "myLastName");
    System.out.println("My Name: " + myName.displayName()); // <-- or this,
    // System.out.println("My Name: " + myName); // <-- but the advantage of performing
                                                 // <-- an override on toString() is
                                                 // <-- that this implicit `toString()`
                                                 // <-- will work.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to override `toString()`

something like

```
public String toString()
{
return first+" "+ middle+" "+last;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class name lacks a `toString()` method, and inherits the default one from `Object` which prints the class name and memory address.

Replace:

```
public String displayName(){    
    return first + " " + middle + " " + last; 
}
```

With:

```
public String toString() {    
    return first + " " + middle + " " + last; 
}
```

Comment: Wow, what an odd coincidence. The tutorial had named the formatting method 'toString' while I named mine 'displayName'. 'toString' just so happened to share a method name with something completely different.

I switch 'myName.toString()' to 'myName.displayName()' and it works great!